# How to get data from API using curl?

Tags: curl, apigee, apigee-baas, apigee127

(I am new to curl and also apigee)

I am trying to get the Body data from API

"https://staging.api.pearson.com/content/scapi/urn:pearson:manifestation:014f333d-ceda-476f-81f2-d3d6c89ace42"

using curl with following command but unable to get any data than fault string

curl "https://staging.api.pearson.com/content/scapi/urn:pearson:manifestation:014f333d-ceda-476f-81f2-d3d6c89ace42"

Error that I am getting is :

```
{"fault":{"faultstring":"Failed to resolve API Key variable request.header.x-api key","detail":"errorcode":"steps.oauth.v2.FailedToResolveAPIKey"}}}
```

but when accessing the URL multiple times in Browser, I can able to get JSON data as desired

[image]

CURL woking code

```
curl "https://staging.api.pearson.com/content/scapi/urn:pearson:manifestation:014f333d-ceda-476f-81f2-d3d6c89ace42" -H "Accept:application/json"  -H "Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br" -H "Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8 " -H "Connection:keep-alive" -H "Host:staging.api.pearson.com" -H "X-ApiKey:7ij8zrLkCNR9DtAXx3KJ6yutoYnk4SAx" -H "X-PearsonSSOSession:AQIC5wM2LY4Sfczr6fmuhzvfN4dwnpK3c9K8tyduHkwg7sA.*AAJTSQACMDIAAlNLABQtNTk5Nzg3OTI1MTgxNTYxNjE3MAACUzEAAjAx*"
```

Kindly somebody suggest to get JSON data

Sorry I am new to curl and also apigee

Thanks

Comment: https://staging.api.pearson.com/content/scapi/urn:pearson:manifestation:014f333d-ceda-476f-81f2-d3d6c89ace42 does not work at browser too. https://screencast.com/t/vHK3UuKNu

Comment: but I don't know how my chrome got that, anyway could you please go back and forth on the browser by modifying url, then you will get data automatically

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license).  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-route-for-a-dissociation-request).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
curl "URL" \
 -H "Accept: application/json" \
 -H "x-apikey: {need to pass your API key here}" \
 -H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream"
```

Put your x-apikey in {need to pass your API key here}

Comment: Hi Ravikiran : got error as    { "valid" : "false",  "reason" : "App APIKey failed" }  but it's a correct APIKey  but how can chrome can show the data ?

Comment: In the chrome goto developer tools and goto network tab, and check what is the api key header when it is successful in chrome

Comment: bit further, so now got 18 Response headers, should all have to be set while running curl ?

Comment: You need to add request headers. When you follow steps in as per the image, it will only add request headers not response headers

Comment: There is only 3 request headers:  (Provisional headers are shown,
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1, User-Agent:M ) so, these are a valid ?

Comment: That should be fine

Comment: got this error :     {"fault":{"faultstring":"Failed to resolve API Key variable request.header.x-apikey","detail":{"errorcode":"steps.oauth.‌​v2.FailedToResolveAP‌​IKey"}}}

Comment: can you copy the curl on the stackoverflow to see what you did?

Comment: Copied !  pls check

Comment: I am not able to see the curl request what you posted

Comment: Wow I got the answer as per your suggestion, I tried to Get Data using Restlet API and got some request headers then used it in the curl now it works !    AWESOME MAN

Answer (score 2):

[image]

As you said that in the chrome, it is working, on the successful request, you can copy as curl like below

Comment: sorry your image link broken

Comment: the process showed in your image link shows error while running :   {"fault":{"faultstring":"Failed to resolve API Key variable request.header.x-apikey","detail":{"errorcode":"steps.oauth.v2.FailedToResolveAPIKey"}}}

Comment: You should do that after the successful request. As you said before that in the chrome it was working but not in curl.  The above response only happens, if you copy and paste only url. As your chrome is already cached the API key, it was working.

Comment: I do not have an answer

Comment: Thank you so much  Ravikiran !